# Double subscript using MathJax

Tags: subscripts, mathjax

I am trying to stack subscripts in the following way:

[image]

However, I'm trying to do it in another stackexchange website (physics.stackexchange), which uses MathJax (not LaTeX). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subarray`, but in standard LaTeX you have to supplement its definition if you want to use right alignment, because by default it only supports center or left alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{subarray}[1]{%
  \vcenter\bgroup
  \Let@ \restore@math@cr \default@tag
  \baselineskip\fontdimen10 \scriptfont\tw@
  \advance\baselineskip\fontdimen12 \scriptfont\tw@
  \lineskip\thr@@\fontdimen8 \scriptfont\thr@@
  \lineskiplimit\lineskip
  \ialign\bgroup\ifx c#1\hfil\fi\ifx r#1\hfil\fi
    $\m@th\scriptstyle##$\ifx r#1\else\hfil\fi\crcr
}{%
  \crcr\egroup\egroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\psi(x,t)|_{\begin{subarray}{r}x=0\\t=0\end{subarray}}=\psi(0,0)=0
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\psi(x,t)|_{\begin{subarray}{c}x=0\\t=0\end{subarray}}=\psi(0,0)=0
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\psi(x,t)|_{\begin{subarray}{l}x=0\\t=0\end{subarray}}=\psi(0,0)=0
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, `\begin{subarray}{r}` works out of the box in MathJax.

[image]